# Get the currency symbol based on country

Tags: java, android, currency, android-location

I have a TextView which display currencies. By default my textview's text is: `$0.00`
How can I make it so the `$` changes based on user selection.

I have the following code:

```
Locale locale=new Locale("en", "US");
Currency currency=Currency.getInstance(locale);
String symbol = currency.getSymbol();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), symbol, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Which shows `$` but if I have the following:

```
Locale locale=new Locale("en", "AU");
Currency currency=Currency.getInstance(locale);
String symbol = currency.getSymbol();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), symbol, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

it shows `AU$` instead of `$`

How can I set the currency symbol without all the extra stuff?

Comment: Do you have other examples of what it does for other countries monetary symbols?

Comment: I tried your code. It shows "AUD" not AU$. We cannot expect $ for Locale("en", "AU") because its already used for Locale("en", "US")

Comment: Do you know what would be best to display amount, any kind of amount? My app which calculates Toll (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sikni8.tollculator) is currently using the `$` symbol and it makes it not user-friendly outside of the US or anywhere they don't use `$` so what is the best way you think I can display the amount?

Answer (score 4):

If what you want is to add that format to a number you have you could do

```
myString = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(myNumber);
```

for default
or

```
myString = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "AU")).format(myNumber);
```

for specified

Comment: Will it add the currency symbol in front of any number?

Comment: I currently using the following: `tvTotalAmountLabel.setText("$" + tollToString(totalTollAmount));` to  display the amount. How do I replace the $ with the currency of Locale?

Comment: It would depend on what does `tollToString(totalTollAmount)` but you could save your numberFormat instance `NumberFormat numFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();` and every time you need that use it like this `tvTotalAmountLabel.setText(numFormat.format(totalTollAmount));`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression to remove all word characters.

```
    String symbol = currency.getSymbol().replaceAll("\\w", "");
```

However this may not be ideal if any of the monetary symbols you are dealing with use letters.

Comment: Do you know what would be best to display amount, any kind of amount? My app which calculates Toll (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sikni8.tollculator) is currently using the `$` symbol and it makes it not user-friendly outside of the US or anywhere they don't use `$` so what is the best way you think I can display the amount?

Comment: well in java it doesn't show symbol for all the countries so if in case i replace the words there wont be anything??