# How to get currency code for a selected country in android

Tags: java, android

I have a `Spinner` that gives country name, how to get country currency code in Android?

For example
United States America - USD
India - INR

In `Spinner` I have a list of country name.

Comment: Please check previous ans at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260767/get-the-currency-symbol-based-on-country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [web service](http://www.webservicex.net/) that accomplishes [what you're asking](http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?op=GetCurrencyByCountry), and you can find a sample for HTTP GET on Android [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705494/android-http-get-request).